# Wrong passport stamp when entering Schengen

Tags: schengen, passport-stamps

I was flying into Schengen Area (Denmark) from a non-Schengen country (Ireland), and with a non-EU/EEA passport of course I will get a passport stamp every time I cross the Schengen border. But this time when I fly-in I notice that my passport was not stamp with an entry stamp but a exit stamp instead. I guess the immigration officer has taken the wrong stamp to stamp my passport so this happen.

Since Ireland do not issue exit stamp, only with my passport there is no way of proofing that when I enter Schengen Area again, I know it wouldn't matter if I am just staying for a short period of time, but with some other recent visit I am pushing very close to the 90 days visa-free limit.

Would it be possible to go to the airport to get them to fix the stamp? Or is there some other way that I could take care of this problem?

Comment: Keep your boarding pass with your passport.  This will serve as evidence that you were given the wrong stamp, and, more importantly, will serve as evidence that you entered the Schengen area on that date.

Comment: I'm fairly sure their computer systems have the correct information. I would contact ge airport and let them know jus to be sure.

Comment: @AyeshK there is no Schengen-wide computer system for tracking entries and exits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to @phoog's suggestion, I kept my boarding pass and did a little more.

Since I was worried that it would give me trouble when I'd leave the Schengen Area, I went to the airport police station and they helped me  solve this problem. I just showed them my passport and explained what happened, and after checking my boarding pass, they crossed out the wrong exit stamp and stamped the entry stamp for me. I have not encountered any problem when crossing the Schengen border afterwards.